# Raspberrypi kernel upstream for 5.15.0-1017-raspi

Tags: server, kernel, raspberrypi

I have a kernel patch that I want to apply and be based on the current 5.15.0-1017-raspi which is the latest stable release that Ubuntu 22.04.1 sources point to.

Is the https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux branch 5.15.y the closest upstream to 5.15.0-1017-raspi?

Comment: Are you using the Raspberry Pi OS or Ubuntu?

Comment: Ubuntu Server 22.04.1 for raspberry pi.  Running on a pi4.